Deploying a MongoDB Cluster with Docker give "ReferenceError: <replicateSetName> is not defined" on window powershell but worked on WSL. Why?
So I am following this tutorial Deploying a MongoDB Cluster with Docker from MongoDB and using Powershell. But it gives the error as in the title:
To my understanding I have defined it already in the --replSet and all three of them have the same name, hence it is defined, but it doesn't think so.
Later I used WSL and run the same thing but it worked perfectly this time.
So what caused this exactly?
